# .NET Framework Winforms App on Windows IOT

Tags: winforms, windowsiot

I have a Winforms application built on .NET Framework 4.7 running on client's desktops. Client would like to run it on a tablet running Windows IOT. Is this possible?
I've found a couple of articles indicating it should run on Windows IOT Enterprise, but not Windows IOT. However, I haven't been able to find much specific official documentation.
Can anyone enlighten me and/or point me to some official documentation?

Comment: _"No legacy Win32 UI support: IoT Core does not contain APIs to create classic (HWND) Windows. Legacy methods such as CreateWindow() and CreateWindowEx() or any other methods that deal with Windows handles (HWNDs) are not available. Subsequently, frameworks that depend on such APIs including MFC, Windows Forms and WPF, are not supported on IoT Core"_ - [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore).

Comment: That settles it. Thank you!